# Is there a docker image for minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I couldn't find an official one which suggests that maybe it's a bad idea? My idea was to be able to spin up the whole of minikube and deploy an app to it so that developers are not required to install minikube manually.

If this is indeed possible, is there an already created official minikube docker image?

Comment: Have a look at Rancher k3s (https://github.com/rancher/k3s). You can setup a docker based k8s cluster with just one docker-compose up (https://github.com/rancher/k3s/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). Together with metallb (https://metallb.universe.tf/) you can even use LoadBalancer Services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minikube is not available as Docker image. It's a VM based tool not container based.

Quoting a statement from [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3192#issuecomment-425915749) link.

> Hypervisor based minikube doesn't really work from a docker container
>   and the None driver won't really work either as it relies on systemd
>   to run the kubelet on your machine.

For more info, check [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3192).